# Countdown timer in javascript with Days, Hours, Minutes only - getting rid of Seconds

Tags: javascript, timer, countdowntimer

I'm a noob when it comes to javascript which I just started to learn.
I have been trying to code a timer for my website and I found some code which is helpful in doing so, yet I would like to get rid of the displaying of the seconds.

Here is the javascript code I am using:

```
  const total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  const seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
  const minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  const hours = Math.floor((total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  const days = Math.floor(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  return {
    total,
    days,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  const clock = document.getElementById(id);
  const daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  const hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  const minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  const secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    const t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  const timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

const deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

And here is the html code associated with it:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Timer</title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet"
   type = "text/css"
   href = "style.css" />
  <script src="javascript.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Preorders end in:</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any chance there is a quick fix to this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you very much,

G

Comment: Did you try anything ? What happens e.G. when you simply delete all lines with the word second in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Javascript, remove all lines that deal with `seconds` and `secondsSpan`. In the HTML remove the last `<div>` in `<div id="clockdiv">`.

That would leave you with:

**JS**

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  const total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  const minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  const hours = Math.floor((total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  const days = Math.floor(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  return {
    total,
    days,
    hours,
    minutes
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  const clock = document.getElementById(id);
  const daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  const hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  const minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');

  function updateClock() {
    const t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  const timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

const deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

**HTML**

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Timer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script src="javascript.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Preorders end in:</h1>
  <div id="clockdiv">
    <div>
      <span class="days"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="hours"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="minutes"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```